# Problems with looping through data.table in R. Condition to compare does not change

Tags: r, data.table

I am having a problem with creating a categorical variable in data table.  My goal is to break down the RA variable into different groups, a high group, a medium group and a low group.  The first step is to create different levels based on RA using the quantile function.  This is not a problem:

```
base.dat <- read.csv("file:///C:/Users/Owner/Documents/baseball csv.csv", header=TRUE)
base.dat.70 <- base.dat[base.dat$yearID>=1970, ]
base.dat.70.reduce <- base.dat.70[ , c(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27)]
table <- data.table(base.dat.70.reduce)

table[ ,med.RA:=median(RA), by=yearID]
table[ ,RA.low:=quantile(RA, .33), by=yearID]
table[,RA.high:=quantile(RA, .67), by=yearID]
```

The above code correctly created the RA.low and RA.high variables, which are different for different years.

The issue is with the next block of code.  I want to compare each row with its RA.low and RA.high to place it in a low, medium, or high group.  The condition would be different for different years.  Here is the code:

```
 table[ , RA.level:= { if (RA <RA.low) "Low RA"
  else if (RA <RA.high) "Medium RA"
  else "High RA"}, by=RA] 

kable(head(table))
kable(tail(table))
```

I get a bunch of warnings, 'In if (RA < RA.low) "Low RA" else if (RA < RA.high) "Medium RA" else "High RA" :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used'

I have gotten these before, with for loops for data frames, and I have been able to work through them.  But the output for this one does not quite work.  The first five rows are fine. These are all correct.  If RA is between RA.low and RA.high, it should be Medium RA.  If it is below RA.low, it should be low, and if it is above RA.high it should be high.  These all appear to be correct.  They are all for the same year, so the RA.low and RA.high are all the same.

The problem comes printing out the last six rows of the table.

In the first row an RA of 776 is classified as high, when it should be medium.  In the third row an RA of 704 is classified as high, when it should be low.  In the sixth row an RA of 672 is classified as medium when it should be low.

I was thinking that the evaluation was ONLY being done against the initial values of RA.low and RA.high, the ones for 1970.  But in that case the sixth row should still be low, as RA.low was 677 for 1970, and row three would also be medium, not high.

I apologize for the question, I'm sure the fix is easy.  I just can't quite figure out exactly what is going on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you need `fcase`, see https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/fcase.html

Comment: Would the base function `cut()` also get you what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll demonstrate both `fcase` and (if you're on a version before 1.13.0) nested `fifelse`.

```
MT <- as.data.table(mtcars)

MT[, c("lo", "med", "hi") :=
       .(quantile(disp, 0.33), median(disp), quantile(disp, 0.67)), by = .(cyl)]
MT
#      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb     lo   med      hi
#  1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 160.00 167.6 168.748
#  2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 160.00 167.6 168.748
#  3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  83.83 108.0 120.240
#  4: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 160.00 167.6 168.748
#  5: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 308.06 350.5 360.000
# ---                                                                         
# 28: 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2  83.83 108.0 120.240
# 29: 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4 308.06 350.5 360.000
# 30: 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 160.00 167.6 168.748
# 31: 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 308.06 350.5 360.000
# 32: 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2  83.83 108.0 120.240

MT[, intrvl1 := fcase(
  disp < lo, "low",
  data.table::between(disp, lo, hi), "med",
  disp > hi, "high") ]

MT[, intrvl2 :=
       fifelse(disp < lo, "low",
               fifelse(disp > hi, "high", "med")) ]

MT
#      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb     lo   med      hi intrvl1 intrvl2
#  1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 160.00 167.6 168.748     med     med
#  2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 160.00 167.6 168.748     med     med
#  3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  83.83 108.0 120.240     med     med
#  4: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 160.00 167.6 168.748    high    high
#  5: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 308.06 350.5 360.000     med     med
# ---                                                                                         
# 28: 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2  83.83 108.0 120.240     med     med
# 29: 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4 308.06 350.5 360.000     med     med
# 30: 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 160.00 167.6 168.748     low     low
# 31: 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 308.06 350.5 360.000     low     low
# 32: 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2  83.83 108.0 120.240    high    high
```

Some notes:

- I use `data.table::between` (fully-qualified) because I also often load `dplyr`, and its version of `between` requires that the second and third arguments be length-1, breaking any vectorized operations with it; `data.table::between` accepts all three arguments with the same length (or 1).
- In the `fcase` code, I demonstrate the condition where we don't *need* `between`, since we can test `lo` and `hi` and everything else is between them.
- if you have version 1.13.0 or newer, I strongly urge `fcase` over nested `fifelse`; while the performance might be better (I haven't tested), I argue the readability (and therefore maintainability) of `fcase` is far better. Nested `fifelse` can be easy to miss-indent and forget where in the foray of "ifs" you are.
- while you initially are trying to do this row-wise (with `by=RA`), it's often better to do things in vectors in R. In your attempt, though, you're grouping by a `numeric`, which should typically be unique, but there is certainly room for ambiguity. If you must see a rowwise solution, then better to use `by=seq_len(nrow(DT))`:

  ```r
  MT[, intrvl3 := c("low", "med", "high")[findInterval(disp, c(-Inf, lo, hi, Inf))],
     by = seq_len(nrow(MT))]
  MT
  #      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb     lo   med      hi intrvl1 intrvl2 intrvl3
  #  1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 160.00 167.6 168.748     med     med     med
  #  2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 160.00 167.6 168.748     med     med     med
  #  3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  83.83 108.0 120.240     med     med     med
  #  4: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 160.00 167.6 168.748    high    high    high
  #  5: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 308.06 350.5 360.000     med     med    high
  # ---                                                                                                 
  # 28: 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2  83.83 108.0 120.240     med     med     med
  # 29: 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4 308.06 350.5 360.000     med     med     med
  # 30: 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 160.00 167.6 168.748     low     low     low
  # 31: 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 308.06 350.5 360.000     low     low     low
  # 32: 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2  83.83 108.0 120.240    high    high    high
  ```

  As you can see, this is subject to a right-closed phenomenon.

Comment: Thank you so much for our help!  I am quite new to data table, so this is going to help me a whole lot.